# How do you avoid cycling in a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-optimization

When running the simplex method on a linear programming problem that cycles The only thing I can think of to avoid cycling is to stop running it when the same dictionary appears twice? however i'm not to convinced.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go cycling in the afternoon and do your programming in the evening.

Comment: hahahhaha amazing!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to switch to [Bland's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%27s_rule) temporarily whenever you have a sequence of degenerate pivots; as soon as you get a nondegenerate pivot 
(if that happens before the algorithm terminates), you can switch back to 
your normal pivot selection rules.